# keep const value in Symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony, constants, symfony4

Here is the problem:

I have been trying to keep the value of a const variable if is defined in app.php in Symfony. This is my code.

The design of the app was made it like this. with a constant that indicates what type of system to start.
This is my code.

```
if(!defined("ENTORNO")) {
define("ENTORNO",2,true);
}
```

i'm using "true" to redefine the const value. I have a REST service to redefine the const variable. Like this.

```
     * @Rest\Get("/api/VersionSistema/{id}", name="VersionSistemas")
 */
public function VersionSistemas($id)
{
    try {
        define("ENTORNO",$id);
        return new View(Response::HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new View($e->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

My problem is that in each request the variable loses its value and is reinitialized. So ¿how could I always keep the value with which I redefined the variable?

Comment: Hi, remember that php does not keep context. When your server receive the request, it execute the php script from begin to the end and remove everything which is in memory. You have to store your var in another location. In your case, i think you should store in session (look for Symfony session tools and parameter bags). (note: This is the standard way to use php and symfony use him as it. You can write runner, but really This is not a good idea)

Comment: Also, the third parameter to `define` is whether the constant should be case-sensitive or not, it is not for redefining.